# Creating a PDF table in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pdf

I've been looking for 2 days for a solution to that problem but didn't found anything yet. I need to create a PDF File with only one page which shows its content in a table (like a timetable). I'd like to fill the cells with string values, that I am getting from a XML file.

PDFKit wasn't usefull so far and Quartz 2D appears not to be a solution because it's quit complicated to draw a table which I can change easily. Are there any librarys or so to just create a one-paged-tableshowing PDF? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered putting the data into excel or open office Calc and then exporting to pdf?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach with the greatest flexibility would probably be to generate the table as HTML, use a WebView to display it and render it to PDF using NSView's `dataWithPDFInsideRect:` method.